# Embedding lookup table doesn't mask padding value

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm using an embedding_lookup operation in order to generate dense vector representations for each token in my document which are feed to a convolutional neural network (the network architecture is similar to the one in a [WildML article](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/)).

Everything works correctly but when I pad my document inserting a padding value in it, the embedding lookup generates a vector for this token too. I think that this approach could alterate the results in the classification task. What I want to achieve is something similar to what Torch [LookupTableMaskZero](https://github.com/Element-Research/rnn#rnn.LookupTableMaskZero) does.

1) Is correct what I want to do?

2) Is already implemented something like this?

3) If not, how can I mask the padding value in order to prevent the generation of the corresponding vector for it?

Thank you in advance,

Alessandro

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

@Alessandro Suglia
I think this feature is useful, unfortunately tf not support right now.
One workaround to get the same result but is slower is to lookup twice.
like below

```
  lookup_result = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(emb, index)
  masked_emb = tf.concat(0, [tf.zeros([1, 1]), 
                             tf.ones([emb.get_shape()[0] - 1, 1])
  mask_lookup_result = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(masked_emb, index)
  lookup_result = tf.mul(lookup_result, mask_lookup_result)
```

Answer (score -1):

It seem that in rnn model, we don't need mask the padding value as long as we mask the loss( the loss is same no matter whether we mask the input padding, I get the result by run a test code)!

Of course, zero the padding may speed-up the computation for zero multiply when `sequence_len` parameter in `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` is not passed.

At the end, if the model will do interactive between sequence(such as CNN, convolution may affect the padding embedding), zero padding embedding is necessary.